# Which commentary of the Bhagavata Gita is the best?

Tags: scripture, bhagavad-gita, advaita, adi-shankaracharya, commentary

Sridhara Swami, Adi Shankara & Madhusudana Sarasvati- these 3 stalwarts of Advaita philosophy have composed their respective commentaries on the Bhagavata Gita but neither of them can be considered inferior to the other two. So whose commentary on the Bhagavata Gita is perfect i.e to say answers all questions related to the text ?

Comment: Which commentary is the best is subjective and such questions are not allowed here. Because they are opinion based. BTW welcome to our site!